# CSS flexbox wrap in legacy browsers

Tags: css, flexbox

FMI, old flexbox doesn't support flex-wrap property. There's no wrap in old browsers such as Android 4.3 and Safari 6.
It shows some flex container children in one line and crop the remaining ones.

What are the alternative/fallback solutions?

Comment: You're trying to apply CSS 3 technologies to older browsers. The alternative is CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

http://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox

Just don't use Flexbox and try to solve your layout-problem with CSS that's got a lot wider cross-browser-support (especially backwards) and degrades gracefully for non-supporting browsers without the need for Javascript to somehow make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Modernizr Script to detect whether browser supports flex-wrap property, then you can create fallback solution.

Link to official page: https://modernizr.com/docs
Great article: http://www.westofwonder.com/2014/02/cross-browser-flex-box-for-responsive-design/

Answer (score 1):

If you want `flex-wrap` alternative, you should use `display: inline-block;`. However `display: inline-block;` isn't perfect. So, you should devise the markup like the following code.

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__flex-container">
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list__flex-container">
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="list__flex-item">Item 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```